# how to expect pointer argument which is created later

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googletest, googlemock

I have such group -> element to add/remove, with code snippt:

```
// production code:
Group::add(Element* e) {...};
Group::remove(Element* e) {...};
ElementDerived::ElementDerived(Group* group){ group->add(this);}
ElementDerived::~ElementDerived(Group* group){ group->remove(this);}
```

whenever i want to test the class `ElementDerived`, i have to do the following in the setup/teardown. However, how can I set the argument expectation explicitly without `_`?

```
// test code:
struct Test_ElementDerived : public ::testing::Test {
  void SetUp() override {
    ElementDerived* p = nullptr;
    EXPECT_CALL(group, add(_)) // how to set expection on the pointer argument?
      .WillOnce(Invoke([&p](auto base_ptr) {
        p = static_cast<ElementDerived*>(base_ptr);
      }));
    sut = std::make_unique<ElementDerived>(&group);
  }
  void TearDown() override {
    EXPECT_CALL(group, remove(sut.get()));
  }
  MockGroup group{};
  std::unique_ptr<ElementDerived> sut;
};
```

Comment: EXPECTations should probably be set in TEST bodies, not in the fixture.

Comment: well, i agree, but that is a general rule. in certain cases, actions already take places with constructor. and you see the code snippet, it is not complicated or unreasonable case.

Comment: `EXPECT_EQ(sut.get(), p);` ?

Comment: when add is called, it will be called with certain memory address, which is not known with sut.get() or p.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
 Element* p = nullptr;
 EXPECT_CALL(group, add(_)).WillOnce(SaveArg<0>(&p));
 sut = std::make_unique<ElementDerived>(&group);
 ASSERT_EQ(p, static_cast<Element*>(sut.get()));
```

This does not differ much from what you just did. To replace `_` with some matcher - you would have to know the pointer - the only way to achieve that is to use placement new:

```
 struct DestructCaller {
     template <typename T> void operator()(T* ptr)
     {
        if (ptr) ptr->~T();
     }
 };
 std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(ElementDerived), alignof(ElementDerived)> sut_storage;
 std::unique_ptr<ElementDerived, DestructCaller> sut;

 void SetUp() override
 {

     EXPECT_CALL(group, add((ElementDerived*)&sut_storage));
     sut.reset(new (&sut_storage) ElementDerived(&group));
 }
```

Or similar concept with unrestricted union:

```
 union
 {
     ElementDerived sut;
 };

 void SetUp() override
 {

     EXPECT_CALL(group, add(&sut));
     new (&sut) ElementDerived(&group);
 }
 void TearDown() override
 {

     EXPECT_CALL(group, remove(&sut));
     sut.~ElementDerived();
 }
```

In my personal opinion - a way with SaveArg and ASSERT_EQ is more readable.